# Android - Change size of sliding menu/Expandable menu

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So im writing a application which has a sliding menu on the left hand side which also has a expandable menu within.

One of the menu slots is for current store, which has "My current store" text then we get the store name and place it underneath. For a short store name, it works fine, as per the first screen shot.
[Short store name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smPiN.png)
 However when the store name is quite long, it is cut off and overlapped, as per screen shot 2. 
[long store name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4mdW.png)
I tried to fix this with the below code, but it doesnt work,

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.string.sliding_menu_current_store);
            viewHolder.subTitleText.setLayoutParams(params);
            viewHolder.subTitleText.setText(Application.getInstance().getCurrentStore().getName());
            viewHolder.subTitleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE: Ive changed the code to:

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, R.string.sliding_menu_current_store);
            viewHolder.subTitleText.setLayoutParams(params);
            viewHolder.subTitleText.setText(Application.getInstance().getCurrentStore().getName());
            viewHolder.subTitleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And it seems to work, the only minor issue I have now, is that the store name is right at the bottom of the cell, I would like to a bit off the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that parent view (the parent of subTitleText) has a fixed height.

Try to set the height of the parent as WRAP_CONTENT with a min_height of the previous fixed height.